# Zend Paginator parameters

Tags: pagination, zend-framework2

I'm building a site with Zend 2.3 and what I want to do is to paginate the results using
Zend Paginator. I don't get any error, in fact I can see every link correctly, however they don't work properly.

When I want to paginate the news within a category, Paginator generates the following links:

```
........./index/categories/1
........./index/categories/2
........./index/categories/3
```

............................

Instead the links I want (i.e category 2) should be like:

```
............/index/categories/2/1
............/index/categories/2/2
............/index/categories/2/3
```

This is my module.config:

```
'index'=>array(
                 'type'=>'Segment',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'route' => '/index[/[:action][/:id][/:id2]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                                'action'  =>  '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults'  =>  array(
                                'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                                'action'     => 'index'
                        ),
                    ),
            ),
```

I've already tried passing $cat_id from controller to URL helper ('id'=>$this->id) but it doesn't work. Only it seems to work when I hardcode the id value, for example:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('index', array('action'=>'categories','id'=>3,'id2' => $this->first)); ?>">First </a>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('index', array('action'=>'categories','id'=>$this->id,'id2' => $this->first)); ?>">First </a>
```

So my question is, How can I do it work passing vars to Paginator?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me what this `$this->id` property is -- where's it set? As for the additional route params you can always use your own partial template for the paginator helper and set the url's there.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to create an example with such limited information but generally you'd follow this:

This would be in your controller

```
// This is some array of data that you've pulled from a data source
$arrayOfYourData = array();

$paginator = new \Zend\Paginator\Paginator(new \Zend\Paginator\Adapter\ArrayAdapter($arrayOfYourData));
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(25);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber((int) $this->params()->fromQuery('page',1));

// now return $paginator to your view by assigning it to ViewModel, etc
```

Then in your **view** you would have something like this example

```
  <?php echo $this->paginationControl($paginator, 'Sliding', 'your-namespace/pagination_control.phtml', array('route'=>'some/route', 'routeOptions'=>array('action'=>'some-action')); ?>
```

and then you should have a views/your-namespace/pagination_control.phtml as such:

```
<?php if ($this->pageCount): ?>
<div class="paginationControl">
<?php echo $this->firstItemNumber; ?> - <?php echo $this->lastItemNumber; ?>
of <?php echo $this->totalItemCount; ?>

<!-- First page link -->
<?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route, array('page' => $this->first)); ?>">
    First
  </a> |
<?php else: ?>
  <span class="disabled">First</span> |
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- Previous page link -->
<?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route, array('page' => $this->previous)); ?>">
    &lt; Previous
  </a> |
<?php else: ?>
  <span class="disabled">&lt; Previous</span> |
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- Next page link -->
<?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route, array('page' => $this->next)); ?>">
    Next &gt;
  </a> |
<?php else: ?>
  <span class="disabled">Next &gt;</span> |
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- Last page link -->
<?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route, array('page' => $this->last)); ?>">
    Last
  </a>
<?php else: ?>
  <span class="disabled">Last</span>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```